# Attribute- and value- Mapping algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, attributes, mapping, artificial-intelligence

i have the topic of my computer science thesis. I have to develope an algorithm that after an upload of an excel file for example attributes and values mapps. I mean, this algorithm should recognize the excel attributes and its values and deliver them as suggestions. Does anybody know how can i begin with this? I mean if there is a framework to use or just where to look at for methods to develop something similar?

I would appreciate any help! 
Thanks
P.S I am a java beginner

Comment: I don't understand exactly what is your question but Apache POI is in Java a library for Microsoft documents. https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Not sure what you want, but you could read the file and write the tuples into a map

Answer (score 0):

If you want around with excel sheets apache poi is mostly widely used framework. Look for the documentation at [this](https://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Java DOM library:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

It is really helpful when it comes to XML.